# How do I rewrite a 'for loop' as a 'while loop' in python?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

This is the loop:

```
for c in "Hi there":
     print(c.upper())
```

This is my attempt of rewriting as a while loop:

```
phrase = "Hi there"
while len.phrase > 0
    print (c.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use an iterator**

```
phrase = "Hi there"
limit = len(phrase);
itery =0;
while itery<limit:
    print (phrase[itery].upper());
    itery+=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things I see wrong here.

First off, you're forgetting to use a colon at the end of the while statement.

```
while len.phrase > 0:
```

Second, a much more efficient way of performing this task is the following:

```
while 1:
```

as 1 will always be true (in the case of Python) and it will perform an infinite loop like your previous attempt seems to be intending to do.